# wso2 getting org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Unsupported SignedSupportingToken

Tags: wso2, ws-security

We are trying to do a poc in wso2 esb to invoke our BE service which is ws-security enabled. We have setup a pass thru proxy in wso2 and configured the endpoint according to [www.soasecurity.org](http://soasecurity.org/2012/11/05/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service-using-wso2-esb/). However, we keep getting the below error when trying to use the pass thru proxy. Please advise if we are doing anything wrong...

```
ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
rg.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unsupported SignedSupportingToken : "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IssuedToken"
       at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:76)
       at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
       at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:426)
       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
       at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:481)
       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:57)
       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:342)
       at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:329)
       at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:173)
       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:184)
       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Unsupported SignedSupportingToken : "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IssuedToken"
       at org.apache.rampart.builder.TransportBindingBuilder.build(TransportBindingBuilder.java:103)
       at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:140)
       at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
       ... 20 more
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is generating this error? How can we help you without code?

Comment: Hi Ed, this is running on wso2 esb and these are the errors captured from the wso2 synapse logs .. we did not write any code..

Answer (score 1):

What is the security policy you are using to secure the BE service?

Seems like the ESB cannot understand the security policy that is being used for the BE service. 
Follow the [blog](http://soasecurity.org/2012/11/05/how-to-invoke-secured-backend-service-using-wso2-esb/) and you will be able to resolve your concern.

Manisha